# Get data from joined table in CakePHP

Tags: cakephp, join, cakephp-2.0, has-and-belongs-to-many

I need to get data(all the id of the assurance that related to that Indicator datum) from assurances_indicator_data,and I didn't know the right way to join data in CakePHP my code didn't work and it return an empty array.

IndicatorDatum Model :

```
public $hasAndBelongsToMany = array(
        'Assurance' => array(
            'className' => 'Assurance',
            'joinTable' => 'assurances_indicator_data',
            'foreignKey' => 'indicator_datum_id',
            'associationForeignKey' => 'assurance_id',
            'unique' => true,
            'conditions' => '',
            'fields' => '',
            'order' => '',
            'limit' => '',
            'offset' => '',
            'finderQuery' => '',
            'deleteQuery' => '',
            'insertQuery' => ''
        )
    );


function getIndicatorDataAssurance($indi_id){
             $assuranceData = $this->find('all',array(
                'joins' => array(
                     array('table' => 'assurances_indicator_data',
                           'type' => 'INNER',
                        'conditions' => array(
                    'AssurancesIndicatorData.indicator_datum_id' => $cun_indi)))));


            return $assuranceData;


             }


 }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way to join tables in CakePhp is to have to models each representing a table in your database.
An example below, you can modify it to the names of your tables and models:

```
class ModelOne extends AppModel{
   public $belongTo = array('ModelTwo');

}


class ModelTwo extends AppModel{
    public $hasMany = array('ModelOne');

}
```

Then in your controller if you query any of these models, your response array should contain data from both tables.